# Are minimal polynomials of algebraic numbers expressible in radicals always solvable?

Tags: minimal-polynomials, rationalising-denominator

I mean both "solvable" and "expressible in radicals" in the same senses as in the Abel-Ruffini theorem. It could be paraphrased "given an irreducible polynomial with one root that is expressible in radicals, are the rest of the roots also expressible in radicals?"

The context for the question is in service of rationalizing the denominators of arbitrary numbers expressed in radicals. Wikipedia says this is done by multiplying the numerator and denominator by all algebraic conjugates of the denominator, which I would think would entail finding the minimal polynomial over the rationals of the denominator, then finding all roots of this polynomial; if the answer to the question is no, this method would sometimes fail. In that case, I would wonder whether the denominator rationalization problem is also not always solvable, or if it might be solvable by another method.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then the answer is yes. Note that roots of a polynomial form an orbit under the Galois action, and a sum of radicals always maps to a sum of radicals under a Galois action.

Comment: @ThomasGrubb I'm finding a definition of "Galois action" surprisingly not forthcoming from a Google search, but this sounds promising. If I have a polynomial, the Galois group associated with it, and one root, is the idea that I can generate all the other roots by applying the action to the one I have?

Comment: Yes, exactly. By Galois action I just mean any automorphism of say $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}$. In principle you only need automorphisms of a smaller intermediate field $K$, but adding the extra ones doesn't hurt.

Comment: @ThomasGrubb How can such an automorphism be found? All the Galois theory stuff I've found has assumed one already has all the roots of a polynomial, then identifies the automorphisms with permutations of those roots. I assume what I need is a rather a characterization of an automorphism that explicitly specifies which algebraic number every algebraic number gets sent to, since the whole point is that I don't already have all the roots.